# MSIL Property Setter - Access to the value field

Tags: cil

I have the following setter-method, but the object I put in `value` isn't put through to the called method:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname instance void set_SeatingCapacity(int32 'value') cil managed
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor()
    .maxstack 3
    L_0000: ldc.i4 0x6c
    L_0005: ldarg.0 
    L_0006: ldfld int32 Young3.FMSearch.Core.Entities.InGame.BaseObject::MemoryAddress
    L_000b: ldarg.1 
    L_000c: call void Young3.FMSearch.Core.Managers.PropertyInvoker::Set(int32, int32, object)
    L_0011: ret 
}
```

I want to call the function in `L_000c` like `Set(0x6c, ldfld MemoryAddress, value)`. The first two fields are correctly posted to the function. Any clue? It looks quite well when doing something similar and looking at the definition in Reflector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do a `box int32`, or by making `Set` into `Set<T>`.